# PHP datetime createFromFormat fails. why?

Tags: php, datetime

Ok- here's what Im doing:

```
$dateString = "2015-06-12 06:01 am";
$dtUtc = new \DateTimeZone("UTC");
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:i a', $dateString, $dtUtc);

if ($dt === false) {
    die('failed');
}
```

^ it always fails. why? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you don't have to spam 4 times y or 2x m only 1x ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), you want:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d g:i a', $dateString, $dtUtc)
```

Note that `Y` is "4 digit year", `m` is "zero-padded month", `d` is "zero-padded day", and `g` is "zero-padded hour". Admittedly it's quite odd to see a zero-padded hour *and* an AM/PM designator. If you also want to handle "6:01 am" you would want to go back to `h` instead of `i`.

Comment: A wild Jon Skeet outside of his natural habitat, answering a PHP question :) (Nice explanation of the single format characters)

Comment: @Rizier123 He's trying to get his gold PHP badge :P

Comment: ahh thanks. I should have checked the formatting docs.

Comment: @Machavity: Somewhat shockingly, I already have a silver PHP badge, despite not doing any PHP. Hmm.